# What does << do?

Tags: c#, syntax

Before tellimg me to google, please note that Google will not me search "<<" characters.

I have found the following:

data is a byte array.

> int ResultChannel = data[1] + (data[2] << 8)

How does the << work?

Comment: Actually, [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w.aspx)

Comment: Have you even tried google?

Comment: Have you tried to google << characters? Tell me if you got any luck with it...

Comment: @TerryS But you get the point right? 10 minutes of research is not enough, as is stated in the FAQ.

Comment: Ok, tell me how to search for it if you cannot search these characters and do not know their meaning..

Comment: @TerryS Look for "C# operators".

Comment: "Before tellimg me to google, please note that Google will not me search "<<" characters." Come on! Be creative. Think of different search terms.

Comment: Searching for "C# specification" might be a good start.

Answer (score 6):

Shift Left.

> In C-inspired languages, the left and right shift operators are "<<"
>   and ">>", respectively. The number of places to shift is given as the
>   second argument to the shift operators. For example,
>
> ```
> x = y << 2;
> ```
>
> assigns x the result of shifting y to the left by two bits.

Comment: Not logical, it's bitwise.

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier There are 2 types of shifts, arithmetic and logical. What would be a non bitwise shift?

Answer (score 2):

<< is a [left shift operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w.aspx)

> The left-shift operator (<<) shifts its first operand left by the
>   number of bits specified by its second operand. The type of the second
>   operand must be an int or a type that has a predefined implicit
>   numeric conversion to int.

```
static void Main()
{
    int i = 1;
    long lg = 1;
    // Shift i one bit to the left. The result is 2.
    Console.WriteLine("0x{0:x}", i << 1);
    // In binary, 33 is 100001. Because the value of the five low-order 
    // bits is 1, the result of the shift is again 2. 
    Console.WriteLine("0x{0:x}", i << 33);
    // Because the type of lg is long, the shift is the value of the six 
    // low-order bits. In this example, the shift is 33, and the value of 
    // lg is shifted 33 bits to the left. 
    //     In binary:     10 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  
    //     In hexadecimal: 2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    Console.WriteLine("0x{0:x}", lg << 33);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It a bit shift operator.

It shifts the bits to the left.

For example: the 5 << 3 returns a value that is 5 shifted three placed to the left. Five in binary is:

```
00000101
```

And if you shift that three places to the left you get:

```
00101000
```

Which is 40.